# Generic Type instance with anonymous type as generic argument, how to convert back to original type properly?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I meet this problem when I need to verify some code path in my UT.

I need to convert back to its original type to verify the data field is correctly set.

I abstract the class define and my UT is now in the main function for this example

```cs
public interface ITestInterface { };


public class TestClass<T> : ITestInterface
{
    public T member { get; set; }
}

public static class Util
{
    public static ITestInterface Create<C>(C t)
    {
        return new TestClass<C> { member = t };
    }

    public static ITestInterface CreateInstance()
    {
        return Create(new
        {
            p1 = 100,
            p2 = "string"
        });
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var a = Util.CreateInstance();

        var b = a as TestClass<Object>;
        // this will be "null" in this example
        // So, how can I convert back to its real type?
        // And get the "member" data
    }
}
```

I think this example can explain exactly my question and what I want

Please be more patient about:

1. why you use the anonymous type
2. why you use interface
3. why use template class derived from non-generic interface

I would like to say the code is already there, I cannot change it (at least currently)

What I want to do is:

1. check if that interface is an instance of some class derived from `ITestInterface`
2. if it is, i need to convert back to that type, can verify its member data

So please share some solution/idea based on this scenario.

BTW,

Of course I know I am using "Object" in my last statement to convert back to the type is not good(or obviously wrong), but in fact I do not know which other things I can put here. "object" is just an intuitive try. Please share any property way to handle this case ( maybe more than just something which is just used to replace "object" ).

Comment: There's something I don't understand here. Why are you trying to cast your `a` to `TestClass<object>`?

Comment: Is the goal simply to retrieve, let's say, the `p1` property from the `TestClass` instance returned by `Util.Create`?

Comment: My case is simple, this is used to verify the code in my UT. So I need to get back the data in that interface.

Comment: Why can't you just do `Console.WriteLine(a.member.p1)`?

Comment: `a` is type ITestInterface, it do not have "member"

Comment: This is a [Xyproblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Explain what problem you're trying to solve and why you need it this way? First of all why are you using anonymous type?

Comment: @winterTTr Well you can always use dynamic property access, i.e. `((dynamic)a).member.p1`.

Comment: The loss of type safety that comes with `dynamic` is inevitable, since `Util.Create` returns `ITestInterface`, which a) isn't an interface, b) doesn't expose access to `member` via any statically typed properties, fields or methods. I strongly agree with Sriram here; we need more information on what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel add more description to explain the situation. Sorry for the confusion. But indeed I cannot change the code define now, even though it is not a good way

Comment: As @Asad said you could use `dynamic` to work around. But, think twice before you do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not saying this isn't an XY problem but to answer the question you asked.

If you are in the same scope as your anonymous type, you can use type inference with generics to cast it back to the anonymous type.

In my example below, I create the anonymously typed item before calling Util.Create so that I have an instance of that type in a variable that I can use later.  Then I call the generic method `GetAsTestClass<T>`, which uses type inference, based on the 2nd parameter, to set T to the anonymous type.  Then it returns `item as TestClass<T>`, where T is your anonymous type.

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var anonItem = new
    {
        p1 = 100,
        p2 = "string"
    };

    var a = Util.Create(anonItem);

    var b = GetAsTestClass(a, anonItem);
    // this will be "null" in this example
    // So, how can I convert back to its real type?
    // And get the "member" data

    var c = b.member;
    Assert.AreEqual(100, c.p1);

}

public TestClass<T> GetAsTestClass<T>(ITestInterface item, T silentType)
{
    return item as TestClass<T>;
}
```

**Edit:**

Your specific requirements appear to rule out the type-safe options.  Below are code samples using the non-type safe methods of reflection and dynamics.  Note that for the dynamic version to work, you need a reference to Microsoft.CSharp in your project.

```
var a = Util.Create(new
{
    p1 = 100,
    p2 = "string"
});

var memberAnon = a
    .GetType()
    .GetProperty("member")
    .GetValue(a);

var p1 = memberAnon
    .GetType()
    .GetProperty("p1")
    .GetValue(memberAnon);

Assert.AreEqual(100, p1);
```

or the dynamic way

```
dynamic dynamicVar = a;
Assert.AreEqual(100, dynamicVar.member.p1);
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, it is really insightful. But for my case, it may not be possible. In fact, the anonymous type is not create with the same scope so I cannot have the way to get that `anonItem` to be set. In my real code, `anonItem` is created in the `Util.Create` function and return the `TestClass<anonymous type>` to the outside scope. But your answer is really good for me.